# Comparing multiple videos

Tags: video

Is there a (fast) way to compare different videos files, in order to find identical sequences, without comparing 2 videos frame by frame?

Or is the build-a-hash-of-each-frame-and-compare-it-with-other-hashs-way the only possible solution?

Comment: nothing, i wanted to find a solution first and then choose a suitable language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fisrt step is to compare metadata. If the aspect ratio and the length of the video are very different, there is no need to run a heavy process to conclude that the videos are different.

Then, you may build a kind of hash from existing, rapid functions ( in ffmpeg I guess)
I think of comparing the scene-change timestamps. (result from a "Scene Change Detection Algorithm"

you can process each file, until difference > epsilon . You have to define and compute 'difference' (delta in change number ? in timestamps delay ?...) and epsilon...

My answer is not very clear, but It one way I can think of. Yet, I hope it helps...

Comment: ty, for the "scene change" hint i ll try this on different videos hopefully that will reduce the amount of frames to evaluate.